# Accessing a file location from an EAR deployed on Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have my code deployed as an EAR on WAS7. I want to read a file location that keep getting updated with a set of files. I am already parsing those set of files for further processing in my local environment. However when I deploy the EAR on my server , the file location ( I have put the files inside my project location for testing) is not getting read.

Obviously it gives my "FileNotFoundExcpetion". I am not sure how the file location should be provided?

How can I access that file location, and what should be the way to provide that file location in my code if I have deployed the application on server?
That file location can be any remote file location. just for testing I have imported those files to my local workspace.

Comment: As soon as I deploy my EAR on server, it should look out for the required files at that location. I have put the desired  code to get it done. However I am not able to put the file location properly.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

1) If you include your files at the "src" level in an Eclipse J2EE project, then those files will be included under WEB-INF in your .war (as deployed in your .ear).

2) To read those files at runtime, you'd typically use:

`servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myfile");`

3) Alternatively, you might need to call `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`

Here's a good example:

[How to read a properties file in a web application](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web.html)

Comment: I appreciate your response. But the file location can be any remote location. Just for testing I have put it inside src. And the application must look out for the files as soon as I deploy it on server.

Answer (score 1):

If you need any file location, I'd suggest passing it to application using environment variable in the `web.xml` like this:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>filePath</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>/path/to/file.txt</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

then access it in your code using

```
@Resource(name="filePath", type=String.class)
private String filePath;
```

you will be able to change value of that variable also via console after deployment if you need it.

Comment: I agree with you on this. Actually I have a file location that  has a number of files that I need to parse. And I want that file location to be accessed as soon as I deploy my EAR on server. I am not sure how should I put the file location. I am not sure about the correct way of putting the file location. I always end up with File not Found exception. Could you tell me how should I put it?